# Making Noise with Python

Tags: python, windows, audio, pywin32

I am trying to get python to make noise when certain things happen. Preferably, i would like to play music of some kind, however some kind of distinctive beeping would be sufficient, like an electronic timer going off. I have thus far only been able to make the system speaker chime using pywin32's Beep, however this simply does not have the volume for my application.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

EDIT: I have been using PyAudiere for this, but unfortunately the package has been abandoned. Now I need an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyAudiere turns out to be the most convenient. It allows me to simply play an MP3, rather than generate the sound on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

For cross-platform perfection and maximum flexibility, you could use [pygame.mixer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html).

Answer (score 2):

For windows, you can use the `winsound` standard library: http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html